# Implement GridSearchCV on Autoencoder model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, gridsearchcv

I am not really familiar with Deep learning methods, but I created an Autoencoder model to perform unsupervised anomaly detection (no labels) and I would like to tune its hyperparameter. Here is the code for the model.

```
# data dimensions // hyperparameters 
input_dim = X_train_transformed.shape[1] 
BATCH_SIZE = 256
EPOCHS = 100

autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    # deconstruct / encode
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='elu', input_shape=(input_dim, )), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='elu'),
    
    # reconstruction / decode
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='elu')
    
])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", 
                    loss="mse",
                    metrics=["acc"])
```

overview of model :

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 20        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 10        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 42
Trainable params: 42
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And then, here is the "code" I try to do :

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

scorers = {
    
        'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score),
        'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score),
        'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score)
        }
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']

param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizer)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=autoencoder, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scorers ,n_jobs=-1, cv=3,refit="precision_score")
result = grid.fit(X_train_transformed, X_train_transformed)
```

It's copy/paste from some websites, but I don't understand how to make such think works.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3058/4032119302.py in <module>
     15 param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizer)
     16 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=autoencoder, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scorers ,n_jobs=-1, cv=3,refit="precision_score")
---> 17 result = grid.fit(X_train_transformed, X_train_transformed)
     18 
     19 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    803         n_splits = cv_orig.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
    804 
--> 805         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    806 
    807         parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, pre_dispatch=self.pre_dispatch)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     78                     "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn "
     79                     "estimator as it does not implement a "
---> 80                     "'get_params' method." % (repr(estimator), type(estimator))
     81                 )
     82 

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f486ca23410>' (type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.
```

I am not even sure if I correctly use the right scoring metrics given that,what I usually do is  calculating the mean squared error reconstruction loss to see how well it performs.
I want to tune the activation / optimizers.

And I don't know if it's valuable but I use  an early stopping to not go through all the 100 epochs :

```
# define our early stopping
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0.0001,
    patience=10,
    verbose=1, 
    mode='min',
    restore_best_weights=True
)
```

Comment: `GridSearchCV` expects `scikit-learn`-compatible model but you provide a tensorflow model. You can check out official documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#rolling-your-own-estimator on how to implement scikit-learn compatible model.